# Column wise Total in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|  Item   | Consumption | %Consumption| %Cumulative| Category |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| Item 1  |         500 |       28.17 |      28.17 | A        |
| Item 2  |         450 |       25.35 |      53.52 | A        |
| Item 3  |         350 |       19.72 |      73.24 | A        |
| Item 4  |         200 |       11.27 |      84.51 | B        |
| Item 5  |         150 |        8.45 |      92.96 | B        |
| Item 6  |         100 |        5.63 |      98.59 | B        |
| Item 7  |          10 |        0.56 |      99.15 | C        |
| Item 8  |           4 |        0.23 |      99.38 | C        |
| Item 9  |           2 |        0.11 |      99.49 | C        |
| Item 10 |           6 |        0.34 |      99.83 | C        |
| Item 11 |           3 |        0.17 |     100.00 | C        |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

I want the sum of `ConsumptionPercent` in display cumulative column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT [Item]
   ,[Consumption]
   ,[ConsumptionPercent]
   ,SUM([ConsumptionPercent]) OVER (ORDER BY ([Item]) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [Cumulative]
   ,[Category]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Hi, Mjoy I want last row is coming 100% but its coming 999.99 it would be possible ?

Comment: I believe the last row is coming as 99.99 and not 999.99, what is the data type of the ConsumptionPercent column ?

Comment: Its result not column

Comment: Perhaps this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=040935947e02c771186544f030007452) might help you figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try below query using window function `SUM`

```
select Item,
    Consumption,
    ConsumptionPercent,
    sum(ConsumptionPercent) over (order by id),
    Category
from (
    select cast(substring(Item, 6, length(item)) as int) id, *
    from MyTable
) a
```